# Como salvar checkbox de metabox com valores múltiplos

Tags: php, wordpress, post

Tenho um *loop* onde nele é mostrado as taxonomias dos grupos no formato de `checkbox`, porém ao salvar, só salva o último `checkbox` marcado.

Gostaria de saber como salvar todos campos checados?

```
<?php
function noticias_dados_meta_box($post){
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $grupos = isset($values['grupos']) ? esc_attr($values['grupos'][0]) : '';
    wp_nonce_field( 'novos_dados_cliente', 'dados_cliente_nonce' );
?> 

    <!-- checkbox GRUPOS -->
    <label for="grupos">Grupos</label> <br> <br>
<?php 
        $categories=get_categories('title_li=&taxonomy=grupo');  
        foreach($categories as $category) { 
            if ($category->term_id == $grupos) {
                echo "<input type='checkbox' name=‘grupos[]' value='$grupos' checked='true' />";
                echo $category->cat_name;
                echo '<br>';   
            } 
            else{ 
                echo "<input type='checkbox' name=‘grupos[]' value='$category->term_id' />"; 
                echo $category->cat_name;
                echo '<br>';    
            }
        }
}// fecha a função noticias_dados_meta_box

add_action( 'save_post', 'noticias_dados_meta_box_save' );
function noticias_dados_meta_box_save( $post_id ){
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;        
    if( !isset( $_POST['dados_cliente_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['dados_cliente_nonce'], 'novos_dados_cliente' ) ) return;
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    if( isset( $_POST['grupos']))
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'grupos', $_POST['grupos']);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Para enviar campos com múltiplos valores é necessario adicionar `[]` ao `name`. Assim `grupos` será um array e depois basta um foreach para acessar todos o valores.

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='grupos[]' value='$grupos' checked='true' />";
```

O foreach vai atualizar cada checkbox:

```
if( isset( $_POST['grupos'])){
   foreach($_POST['grupos'] as $valor_grupo){
      update_post_meta( $post_id, 'grupos', $valor_grupo);
   }
}
```

Comment: Olá 'perdeu'! O foreach que você está falando é esse: foreach($categories as $category)?
Pois quando adiciono o [ ] nao salva valor algum.

Comment: Não, o `foreach` é para recuperar os checkbox marcados.

Comment: Ainda não consegui fazer. Não sou boa em php, estou iniciando agora. Não sei onde inserir esse outro foreach para recuperar os dados.

Comment: Esse foreach vc coloca no arquivo que na action da tag `<form>`.

Comment: Não tenho a tag <form> pois estou usando metabox para mostrar os checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

Altere o seu `foreach`:

```
if ($category->term_id == $grupos) {
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='grupos[]' value='$grupos' checked='true' />";
    echo $category->cat_name;
    echo '<br>';   
} 
else{ 
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='grupos[]' value='$category->term_id' />"; 
    echo $category->cat_name;
    echo '<br>';    
}
```

A alteração feita foi adicionar `[]` a frente do name `grupos` dizendo com isso que para esse mesmo **name** (grupos) poderá existir mais de um valor.

Então sua resposta (para essa requisição / POST por exemplo), será algo do tipo (se você executar um `var_dump($_POST['grupos'])` ou `print_r($_POST['grupos'])`.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 13
)
```

Sendo `0, 5, 13` os valores selecionados.

A partir dai basta tratar esse retorno e salvar da maneira desejada.

*Obs.: claro que isso tudo que apresentei acima está sendo feito da maneira mais crua/manual possível, não utilizando qualquer helper/function do WP*

### EDITADO

O que você pode fazer na página onde você salva é o seguinte (ou algo do tipo):

```
$grupos = $_POST['grupos'];

foreach ($grupos as $value) {
  // aqui você mantém o código que executava o save anteriormente
  // PORÉM troca o valor/variavel antigamente adicionada por $value
}
```

Caso seja possível, adicione o seu código aqui.