# Delete em multiplos POSTS com checkbox

Tags: php

Já tenho implantado em meu site um link para cada postagem que deleta através do ID no banco de dados.

AO clicar no botão para excluir, o link envia para a pagina 'excluir.php' que executa o comando e volta para a página anterior.

Gostaria de saber como faço para que, através dos checkbox do HTML, eu possa selecionar vários posts e apaga-los de uma só vez?

**Segue o script de listagem dos posts funcionando:**

```
<form action="deleta.php" method="post">
    <ul class="lista-posts">
        <li class="seleciona"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="deletar[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?> " /></li>
        <li class="titulo"><?php echo '.$row['titulo'].'; ?></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

**DELETA.PHP**

```
if( !empty( $_POST['deletar'] ) ) {
   $groups = array_chunk( $_POST['deletar'], 50 );
   foreach ( $groups AS $group ) {
$group = implode('\',\'', $_POST['deletar']);
        $query = 'DELETE FROM conteudo WHERE id IN (\''. $group .'\')';
       $deleta = mysqli_query($conecta, $query);
      // executa a query
   }    
    if($deleta) {
       header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."");
       exit;
} else {
    echo mysqli_error($conecta);
}    
} else {
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."");
       exit;
}
```

Comment: Veja isto - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92898/deletar-apenas-checkbox-selecionados-php/92917#92917

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/7064/91

Comment: Poste o erro inteiro, não só um pedaço, faltou informar o arquivo. Uma duvida, por que seu php esta em Francês?

Comment: O erro que consta na página é somente esse. Bom, sempre que recebo esse tipo de erros com banco de dados mysql vem em frances. Para que eu pudesse receber o erro, adicionei um else na condição da seguinte forma: } else { echo mysqli_error($conecta);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente seu `form` pode ter essa estrutura:

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="checkbox" name="deletar[]" value="1" />Banana<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="deletar[]" value="2" />Pera<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="deletar[]" value="3" />Maçã<br>
</form>
```

Obviamente, você vai gerar os `inputs` em um *loop* em PHP, e no *value* vai colocar o Id de cada ítem a ser deletado.

O "segredo" aqui (que não é segredo nenhum, tem na documentação do PHP) é colocar as chaves `[]` na propriedade "name", para o PHP receber os dados como *array*

e no PHP basta isso:

```
if(!empty($_POST['deletar'])) {
   foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $id) {
      // Aqui voce faz a operacao com o ID desejado
   }
}
```

### Montando a *query* do delete:

Para deletar, efetivamente, você pode usar essa sintaxe, dependendo do DB:

```
DELETE FROM minha_tabela WHERE ID IN ( id1, id2, id3, ... );
```

que pode ser montada facilmente com PHP:

```
if(!empty($_POST['deletar'])) {
   $query  = 'DELETE FROM minha_tabela WHERE ID IN (';
   $query .= implode( ',', $_POST['deletar'] );
   $query .= ');';
   // executa a query
}
```

O ideal é que isso seja otimizado de maneira a agrupar os resultados em lotes, para não ficar gigantesca a cláusula IN da query:

```
if( !empty( $_POST['deletar'] ) ) {
   $groups = array_chunk( $_POST['deletar'], 50 );
   foreach ( $groups AS $group ) {
      $query = 'DELETE FROM minha_tabela WHERE ID IN (' . implode( ',', $group ) . ');';
      // executa a query
   }
}
```

Desta maneira, a cada 50 registros será executada uma *query*. Para consistência, pode ser o caso de agrupar tudo em uma *transaction*, mas aí já depende do caso real de uso, assim como a sanitização dos valores de entrada.

### Alternativas para outras situações:

Nada impede de você usar outras estruturas, mas seria o caso de escolher a mais adequada para o caso real. Eis um exemplo "improvisado" de fazer de outra forma:

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="checkbox" name="id_1" value="x" />Banana<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="id_2" value="x" />Pera<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="id_3" value="x" />Maçã<br>
</form>
```

e no PHP:

```
foreach( $listaDeIds as $id ) {
   if( isset( 'id_' . $id ) {
      // Aqui voce faz a operacao com o ID desejado
   }
}
```

Esta segunda forma não é adequada para o seu caso por precisar ter uma lista de IDs antecipadamente, só pus como exemplo de que há várias maneiras de se mexer com a sintaxe dependendo do contexto.

Um exemplo em que essa sintaxe faria sentido, é se em vez de um *checkbox* para deletar, você tivesse um *radiogroup* por ítem, com opções "deletar", "arquivar", "não fazer nada", por exemplo. Mas mesmo assim, teria outras várias maneiras de se resolver o mesmo problema.

Comment: Como já teve negativação, tou aproveitando pra avisar que se alguém tiver sugestão de melhoria ou correção, ou não gostou da resposta, pode avisar sem medo, que eu não devolvo negativos por vingança, como tive a impressão que acontece no SOpt às vezes. Se for observação boa eu aproveito. Se não for algo que eu concorde, posso até explicar por que não. Aliás, é por isso que eu pude aprender o que eu sei hoje. Crítica inteligente me ensina mais do que elogios. Mas se o votante não tiver nada a dizer, tá valendo também. Sou defensor de as pessoas terem a opção de votar em segredo aqui no SOpt.

Comment: Olá!  
Sua resposta foi perfeita. Porém, talvez por falta de entendimento da minha parte, me senti na necessidade de dizer que me parece que faltam informações, ou elas estão estampadas em minha cara e eu não soube utiliza-las.  
Irei atualizar meu post e adicionar as informações e também como tudo está acontecendo, para que possa me auxiliar novamente.

Comment: @ThiagoBarros vou tentar adequar para as atualizações. Só me explique melhor a parte que você fala "vários checkbox, pois com a sua atualização eu tou vendo um link pro deletar, e não um checkbox. O checkbox é pra ir no lugar do link?

Comment: É que em meu sistema cada post está gerando um link para apagar. Na sua opinião seria redundância deixar o link e o checkbox? Porque o link deleta um único id, e com o checkbox poderia deletar vários..

Comment: @Thiago é dificil eu falar sem visualizar o que vc ta imaginando. Só penso que se é pra deletar com checkbox, teria um monte deles um do lado de cada post, e um botão só pra deletar. Se o cara quer deletar um só, ele marca um só, não?

Comment: Realmente essa parece ser a melhor maneira. Portanto, creio que não irei precisar mais do meu link para excluir o post, não é? Agora que terão os checkbox. Consegue adaptar o código? Eu tentei e não consegui ..

Comment: Basicamente é trocar o link por `<input type="checkbox" name="deletar[]" value="'.$row['id']'" />`, antes do loop ponha o `<form action...` e depois do loop `</form>`. Aí precisa decidir onde vai por o botão de deletar.

Comment: Ate ai tudo bem.. E como ficaria a pagina de deletar, porque o código que voce demonstrou é totalmente diferente do meu atual, que no caso so funciona para um id especifico..

Comment: @ThiagoBarros o loop de deletar é aquele que eu pus, tá praticamente pronto, inclusive com a query. Só questao de o botao de deletar mandar pra ele. Dei 2 opções inclusive, a 2a é mais segura, que deleta em lotes.

Comment: Recebi o seguinte erro: Erreur de syntaxe pr�s de ')' � la ligne 1. Atualizei a minha pergunta lá em cima, para que você possa ver como montei tudo até agora. Mais uma vez obrigado pela atenção!