# Como deletar vários clientes por checkbox?

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como que posso fazer para deletar mais de um cliente conforme selecionado o `checkbox`. Eu tenho dentro de um formulário o completo:

```
<form method="post" action="../sys/del.php">
                      <?php
                        require "../sys/conexao.php";
                        $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM contato");
                        while ($aux = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                        $id = $aux['id_contato']; 
                        $nome = $aux['nome'];
                        $email = $aux['email'];
                        $assunto = $aux['assunto'];
                        $mes = $aux['mensagem'];
                        $hora = $aux['hora'];

                        print"
                        <tr>
                          <td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"valor[]\" id=\"$id\" value=\"$id\"/></td>
                          <td class=\"mailbox-star\"><a href=\"\"><i class=\"fa fa-star text-yellow\"></i></a></td>
                          <td class=\"mailbox-name\"><a href=\"read-mail.html\">$nome</a></td>
                          <td class=\"mailbox-subject\"><b>Kamilla Peliculas - Contato</b> - $assunto</td>
                          <td class=\"mailbox-attachment\"></td>
                          <td class=\"mailbox-date\">$hora</td>
                        </tr>";}
                        mysqli_close($mysqli);
                        ?>                        
                      </tbody>
                    </table><!-- /.table -->
                  </div><!-- /.mail-box-messages -->
                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                <div class="box-footer no-padding">
                  <div class="mailbox-controls">
                    <!-- Check all button -->
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="submit" name="excluir" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                    </div>
                    </form>
```

E esse formulário manda para a página que vai pegar o valor desses `checkbox` selecionados e excluir, porém ele dá o seguinte erro:

> Notice: Undefined index: valor in C:\xampp\htdocs\novo\sys\del.php on
>   line 5
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\novo\sys\del.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: val in C:\xampp\htdocs\novo\sys\del.php on
>   line 12

Alguém pode me ajudar com esse problema, não estou conseguindo achar o erro.

Código da páina PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['excluir'])){
    require_once"conexao.php";

    foreach($_POST['valor'] as $ck){
        $val = $v;
        mysqli_query($mysqli, "DELETE  FROM contato WHERE id_contato = '$val'");
    echo"<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"Campo Deletado Com Sucesso!\");
            history.go(-1);</script>\n";
            mysqli_close($mysqli);
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu postei uma solução pra isso nessa questão: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103910/delete-em-multiplos-posts-com-checkbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segue possível correção:

```
if( isset( $_POST['excluir'] ) && isset( $_POST['valor'] ) ) {
    require_once"conexao.php";

    foreach($_POST['valor'] as $val){
        mysqli_query($mysqli, "DELETE  FROM contato WHERE id_contato = '$val'");
        echo 'Deletando' .$val. '<br>';

    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
} else {
   echo 'Dados não recebidos<br>';
}
```

Você estava usando uma variável que não existia. Aproveitei e tirei aquele echo do meio do *loop*, ele estava no lugar errado e ia gerar um script para cada registro a deletar.

Tem vários ítens que foram observados pelo @rray, em uma resposta que foi removida. Mas se ele restaurar, o meu +1 já está lá, pois é parte fundamental da solução do problema ;)

De qq forma, recomendo dar uma olhada [nessa postagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103910/delete-em-multiplos-posts-com-checkbox), que tem uma solução mais completa pra fazer cada *query* deletar vários registros de uma vez só.

Aqui, uma sugestão de melhoria para legibilidade do `form`:

```
<form method="post" action="../sys/del.php">
.. aqui vai o cabeçalho da tabela, depois da abertura do form..
<?php
   require "../sys/conexao.php";
   $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM contato");
   while ($aux = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
   $id = $aux['id_contato']; 
   $nome = $aux['nome'];
   $email = $aux['email'];
   $assunto = $aux['assunto'];
   $mes = $aux['mensagem'];
   $hora = $aux['hora'];

   echo <<<EOB
         <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="valor[]" id="$id" value="$id"/></td>
            <td class="mailbox-star"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-star text-yellow"></i></a></td>
            <td class="mailbox-name"><a href="read-mail.html">$nome</a></td>
            <td class="mailbox-subject"><b>Kamilla Peliculas - Contato</b> - $assunto</td>
            <td class="mailbox-attachment"></td>
            <td class="mailbox-date">$hora</td>
         </tr>
EOB;
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>             
      </tbody>
   </table><!-- /.table -->

      .. etc ...
</form>
```

A mudança aqui foi colocar o `<form>` e `</form>` fora de todo o markup da tabela, e o uso do [HEREDOC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14258/70) para facilitar a leitura da parte PHP.